# python lambda, numpy help to find sum of time

Tags: python, numpy, lambda

I have the following lists,

```
Events = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
Details = ['Start', 'End', 'Start', 'Start', 'End', 'End]
Time = [0, 1, 4, 5, 10, 16]
```

I need to group individual events in the following way:

```
Event 0:
Sum of Start Times = 0+4 = 4
Sum of End Times = 1+16 = 17
Total time spend by event 0 = 17-4 = 13

Event 1:
Sum of start times = 5
Sum of end times = 10
Total time spend by event 1 = 10-5=5
```

I want some shorthand version for doing this. When there are huge number events and large number of timings for them, then it becomes time consuming to define for-if loop kind of syntax as would be done in Java.

Is there an efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like an option you can do the following:

```
result = {}
for e, d, t in zip(Events, Details, Time):
    result.setdefault(e, {})
    result[e].setdefault(d, 0)
    result[e][d] += t

print result
>>> {0: {'Start': 4, 'End': 17}, 1: {'Start': 5, 'End': 10}}
```

After that it's easy to produce the output you expected.

UPDATE:

Thanks to @abarnert:
    from collections import Counter

```
result = {}
for e, d, t in zip(Events, Details, Time):
    result.setdefault(e, collections.Counter())[d] += t
print result
>>> {0: Counter({'End': 17, 'Start': 4}), 1: Counter({'End': 10, 'Start': 5})}
```

Thanks to @AMacK:

```
result = {}
for e, d, t in zip(Events, Details, Time):
    result.setdefault(e, {}).setdefault(d, []).append(t)

print result
>>> {0: {'Start': [0, 4], 'End': [1, 16]}, 1: {'Start': [5], 'End': [10]}}
```

Best Regards,
Artem

Comment: Ack, you beat me to it! You can also change result[e].setdefault(d, 0) to result[e].setdefault(d, []).append(t) and delete the following line to retain the component values.

Comment: @AMacK, i tried to make it simplier for understanding, but thank you, you are right

Comment: If you're going to use `setdefault`, you can use the returned value directly. For example, replace all three lines with a single line, `result.setdefault(e, collections.Counter())[d] += t` or (for @AMacK's version, `result.setdefault(e, {}).setdefault(d, []).append(t)`).

Comment: Wow thats cool. Can someone tell me what this setdefault() does here? Also how to sum the '1's and '0's and then subtract them. There are cases where '0's might be empty or have fewer values than '1's . How could that be dealt?

Answer (score 2):

With Numpy, you would do it like this:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> Events = np.array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0])
>>> Details = np.array(['Start', 'End', 'Start', 'Start', 'End', 'End'])
>>> Time = np.array([0, 1, 4, 5, 10, 16])
>>> is_start = (Details == 'Start')
>>> sum_start = np.bincount(Events[is_start], Time[is_start])
>>> sum_end = np.bincount(Events[~is_start], Time[~is_start])
>>> durations = sum_end - sum_start
>>> durations
array([ 13.,   5.])
```

This will be faster (~ 10x) than the Python loop based approach, if your data is already in Numpy arrays. If your data is not already in Numpy arrays, it will only be slightly (< 2x) faster than the loop as going through big Python lists is slower than actually doing the counting.

```
import numpy as np

def evcount(events, details, time):
    events = np.asarray(events)
    details = np.asarray(details)
    time = np.asarray(time)

    is_start = (details == 'Start')
    sum_start = np.bincount(events[is_start], time[is_start], minlength=nbins)
    sum_end = np.bincount(events[~is_start], time[~is_start], minlength=nbins)
    return sum_end - sum_start

def evcount2(events, details, time):
    result = {}
    for e, d, t in zip(events, details, time):
        result.setdefault(e, {}).setdefault(d, []).append(t)
    return result

n = 20000
nbins = 200

events_arr = np.random.randint(0, nbins, n)
events = events_arr.tolist()
times_arr = np.random.rand(n)
times = times_arr.tolist()
details_arr = np.array(['Start', 'End'])[np.random.randint(0, 2, n)]
details = details_arr.tolist()

def doit_numpy_list():
    evcount(events, details, times)

def doit_numpy_arrays():
    evcount(events_arr, details_arr, times_arr)

def doit_loop():
    evcount2(events, details, times)
```

and

```
In [34]: %timeit doit_numpy_list()
100 loops, best of 3: 4.03 ms per loop

In [35]: %timeit doit_numpy_arrays()
1000 loops, best of 3: 781 µs per loop

In [36]: %timeit doit_loop()
100 loops, best of 3: 6.18 ms per loop
```